# Catalog URL Rewrites ReIndex - Observer Event

Tags: magento-1.7, catalog, event-observer, reindex

I need to hook into Magento and run some code after "Catalog URL Rewrites" has been re-indexed.

I've looked for a single event to hook into but cannot find any answers. I know how to set-up the observer etc, I just literally need the event to watch, and fire my code afterwards.

I've logged the dispatch event to see what is loaded when re-indexing, but unless I'm'm mistaken, no single event fires relating to the Catalog URL Rewrites.

Anyone know which event would be best?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not think there is an event that will cover all catalog rewrites (i.e. category, product and normal urls) but you could cover all three with the following events.

```
after_reindex_process_catalog_url_category
after_reindex_process_catalog_url_product
after_reindex_process_url_redirect
```

These are called after each index is completed and is fired via.

```
Mage::dispatchEvent('after_reindex_process_' . $this->getIndexerCode());
```

Where the indexer code is one of the following.

```
cataloginventory_stock
catalog_product_price
catalog_url_category
catalog_url_product
url_redirect
catalog_category_product
catalogsearch_fulltext
tag_summary
catalog_product_attribute
```